# Replace COM DLL with new managed COM Callable assembly

Tags: com, interop, code-generation

Is there a smart way to scaffold a COM callable .NET class library from an existing native COM DLL?

### Scenario

Suppose you have a COM based C++ Win32 application and you want to replace one of the COM DLLs with something written from scratch.

### Constraints

1. The new library shall be written in C#, targeting the .NET Framework (4.x)
2. No modifications to the rest of the existing unmanaged application shall be required.
3. No recompilation of the unmanaged code shall be required.

### What I already know

- You can create .NET assemblies which are COM callable.
- You can import the type library IDL from an existing COM DLL.
- Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502629/replace-native-c-com-dll-with-net-com-dll) question, what I want should be possible, even if arduous.

### Question

Is there a smart / efficient way to generate the scaffolding code for a COM callable .NET class library with the exact same signature as an existing unmanaged COM DLL so I can replace the DLLs?

There does not need to be any implementation at first, every method could just throw a NotImplementedException for example.

Comment: Signatures are a non-issue.  The client code only ever uses the interfaces and you got those from the type library.  To implement you'd type, say, public class Foo : IFoo {} to implement the IFoo interface.  That gets you red squiggles under IFoo, right-click and select "Implement interface".  Bam.

Comment: COM in its simplest form is "just" a binary contract, a vtable, 100% language agnostic (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040205-00/?p=40733), so your constraints are not really constraints, they outline the benefit of using COM.